# How to implement button cancel in modal multi checkbox

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am seeing the case that the modal multi-checkbox has 2 buttons save and cancel. I checked the box randomly, and click the button cancel, expecting it to uncheck this checkbox, but actually, it doesn't match that.
Example code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/modal-dialog-with-checkbox?file=src%2FApp.js
Thanks for support!!!

So any ideas for this case, I really want to customize the modal multi checkbox to the component compound to usually use?